# Randomize rows values in MySQL based on current data

Tags: mysql, random

I have a MySQL table `wallet` with real data and I want to randomize this data to similar values based on original.

For example, update `amount` column value on `wallet` table with a RAND percent (from -20% to +20%) for all rows.

With PHP will be:

```php
foreach (Wallet:select('id', 'amount')->get() as $row) {
    $row->amount = $row->amount + ($row->amount * (rand(-20, 20) / 100));
    $row->save();
}
```

Something like?:

```sql
UPDATE `wallet` SET `amount` = `amount` + `amount` * IF(RAND() < 0.5, -1, 1) * FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 20) / 100;
```

Thanks!

Comment: And, the problem/question is ?

Comment: If the MySQL query as example is valid.

Comment: `select round(rand()*40-20,2);` will get a random value between -20 and +20

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the solution was easy:

```sql
UPDATE `wallet` SET `amount` = `amount` + `amount` * ROUND(RAND() * 40 - 20, 2) / 100;
```

Thanks to @Luuk.